# What is the best setup for keeping lan and security nvr separate

Tags: home-networking

I've ran a home lan off of router for a long time. Including streaming devices and security DVR. I'm moving to iP nvr camera system and really want to separate my pc's from everything else. Would it be best to setup lan off router for streaming side, the make different subnet for pc's?

Answer (score 1):

The best way might be to use separate VLAN's for the cameras and computers.  Although not all routers support this.  Its hard to tell without a lot more information but that might be something to look at.